# php arrays. How to format for my result

Tags: php

I am pretty new to php and could sure use some help understanding how to get my result the way I need it from a database query.

What I need is an associative array like this, 'bla'=>'bla'. What I am getting from my foreach loop is this from a print:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => test0
        [name] => test0
        [1] => 1
        [customer_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [name] => test
        [1] => 2
        [customer_id] => 2
    )
```

Here is my loop:

```
foreach($res as $key=>$val)
{
  // have no idea..
}
```

Can someone please help me to format my results so that they are like 'index'=>'value'

Thanks for any help.

---

Here is a sample code that uses a foreach but yet pulls an association. I don't get it. I am thinking that my result set with the indexes are because I am not writing the loop correctly. Here is the code that uses the foreach

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$key|$value\n";
    }
}
```

---

Here is the part of the database class that I am using to fetch the results.

```
$returnArray = array();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    if($row)
        $returnArray[$i++] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
return $returnArray;
```

After using the code that was given to me to omit the index numbers, here is what I am now left with. Its close but not what I need.

Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [cust] => bobs auto
)

This is what the above line should read like

```
'1' => 'bobs auto'
```

What I am trying to do is to format the output for a JSON call for a suggestion box.

I cannot get this to work. Here is everything after my db connection.

```
$out_array = array();
foreach($items as $key=>$val)
{
    if(is_int($key))
    {
      continue;
    }
    $out[$key['id']] = $val['cust'];
}



//echo'<pre>';
//print_r($out_array);
//echo'</pre>';

foreach ($out_array as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$key|$value\n";
    }
}
```

---

OK, I think I am coming down to the home stretch. I have what I need sort of. This is the code I have so far.

```
$out_array = array();
foreach($items as $key)
{
    $out_array[$key] = $val;
//$out_array[$key['id']] = $key['cust'];
}
```

Notice that the commented line does not work, It outputs like the id twice but the line that isn't commented out works just fine. Here is the output from that.

```
Array
(
    [8] => 
    [FAT BURGER] => 
)
```

From this point, would I just use another foreach to iterate over the entire set of data? The array output you see above is from a print_r.

---

This is what I now have and it returns the correct association however, I must comment out the strpos condition to get any results back and I don't know why. Am I correct in nesting these foreach loops like I have?

```
$out_array = array();
foreach($items as $key)
{
  //    $out_array[$key] = $val;
  $out_array[$key['id']] = $key['cust'];

  foreach ($out_array as $key=>$value)
  {
      if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false)
      {
          echo "$key|$value\n";
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: What is '$items'?  Is it the original array you printed at the beginning of your post?

Comment: If that is the case, remove your is_int check and it should work (change id to customer_id and cust to name, of course).

Comment: Items is the return value from the db class which holds the array. I will try and remove the is_int to see if that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It works by skipping the integer indices, and putting the non-integer indices into an output array.

```
$out_array = array();
foreach($res as $key=>$val) {
    if(is_int($key)) {continue;}
    $out_array[$key] = $val;
}
```

EDIT:

```
$out_array = array();
foreach($items as $key=>$val)
{
    if(is_int($key))
    {
      continue;
    }
}
$out[$out_array['id']] = $out_array['cust'];


//echo'<pre>';
//print_r($out_array);
//echo'</pre>';

foreach ($out as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$key|$value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir.. That outputs the correct vals. Here is what I now get.
Array ( [id] => 1 [cust] => bobs auto )

Can you please tell me what I have going on that I have to use your code to get the correct results?

Comment: @Jim, what?  I thought the array you posted in your comment is what you expected.  It isn't, then?  What should it be?

Comment: I think you're getting the result of a `mysql_fetch_array()` call without the second parameter set (or set to MYSQL_BOTH). The result is that you get both associative and numeric elements shoveled in.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The result that I posted in THIS comment section is closer to what I need. What I posted in the original comments was what I was getting back from the database class. BTW The db class uses mysql_fetch_assoc then i++ and is then passed as an array. Maybe that helps? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have the db method. Shere should I post it? Here or back up in the original spot where I stated my question? Maybe this will shed light on the issue.

Comment: Please post it back up at the top. That sort of thing is very helpful.

Comment: Ok, great, will do. ALso.. your code was close but not close enough. I'll explain above. Thanks for the hand!

Comment: OK, I see now. Something as simple as `$out[$array['id']] = $array['cust'];` should do the transform you want, although that's no kind of general solution.

Comment: OK, let me give that a try and I will be right back. Also.. Would you mind please explaining that bit of code you just posted? I have seen it used with my db class before but don't understand how it works. OK, brb

Comment: @Jim, My answer (which I posted before I read @Kalium's comment (sorry if I looks like I stole your idea =X)) shows how you'd do this.

Comment: That snippet puts an element into a new array, using a key of the value at index 'id' in $array variable, and sets the value in the new array to the value at index 'cust' in $array.

Comment: Kalium, Thanks for that explanation. Its not that easy to understand though. I think that after I finish this application, I will need to go back and rewrite some of the methods for the db wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

So you don't want the numeric indexes in your array? You must be using [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array), which returns your results with both numeric and string keys. Use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to get an array with only the string keys (the string being the column name).

Comment: The only issue with that is that the entire app depends on the database wrapper. I can't change it now. It is in a class and that is basically all I have. Is there no way to get this based on a fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a MySQL database, the results, if more than one, are returned as a multidimensional array.

When you run the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ...";
$query = mysql_query($query);

while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    //$info is now a single row, associative array
    echo print_r($info);
}
```

the echo print_r displays the results the way you are looking for them now 'index'=>'value'

EDIT: based on comments.

If you absolutely CAN'T get rid of the mysql_fetch_array then you'll have to hack the code.  It's not clean and I strongly advise refactoring but below is the code you'll need to create an array of field name indexes only from what you're given

```
$my_array = array();
$info = $data[0]; //grab the first row of your data set from the original question.
    foreach($info as $index => $value){
        if(!is_int($index)){
            $my_array[$index] = $value;
        }
    }
```

The newly created $my_array will be in the format you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the hand.. The db is mysql. The code sample that I was given uses mysql_fetch_array and NOT assoc and I am bewildered as to how it works for the code given to me but yet not for my own code. I can't see what the difference is.

Comment: fetch_array returns both index as numeric and index as field name.  fetch_assoc returns only index as field name.

Comment: Ah, thanks.. That makes sense, hence "BOTH". Is there a different syntax to switch between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You got this array from a query and result function from PHP, yeah?

If you were using mysql, it's actually easier to do it like below.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbname"); //Create the query to your database
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //Loop through our results from the query
{
    echo($data['fieldname']."<br/>"); //echo out data through the loop
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a foreach instead of a while loop?

Comment: sure. mysql_num_rows($query) will tell you how many rows it returned... but you still have to call mysql_fetch_array/assoc every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = array();

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $ret[$row['id']] = $row['cust'];
}

$json = json_encode($ret);

echo $json;
// Prints something like:
//
// {1:'bob'}
```

Note the use of [`json_encode`](http://us.php.net/json_encode).

Comment: Hey Strager.. The json_encode() is in a JQuery script already. All I have to do is get my data into an array and then I'm golden but this has really turned out to be a small nightmare.

Comment: @Jim, See my comments to your original answer.  Also, why would json_encode be on the jQuery side??  If that's the case you're not transporting using JSON at all!

Comment: You'll have to forgive me. I'm no js or JQuery expert. I'm really trying to learn more of it. It plugin off of the JQ site. All I know is that with the data in this array, the rest is taken care of because my textbox populates with the data.

Comment: Ok, your right. Your snippet of $ret[$row['id']] = $row['cust']; is almost working. I am missing the index column though. I need the key=>val pair togther. I'm only getting the val.

Comment: @Jim, Can you post what you are given (input) exactly as it is given (using print_r) and your expected results (output) exactly as outputted with print_r in your original question?  This would help tremendously.

Comment: Strager, Kalium's code worked perfectly. I got it to work and formats beautifully. Is there a trick to understanding these arrays? They have always been hard for me to understand.

Comment: Strager, Thanks a million. I am still having an issue though with strpos in the foreach loop. Would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, regarding my last question. I was incorrect in nesting the foreach loops. I also had a typo in my code. It is working, finally. Thank you to all that have helped me!